# Published pages not getting reflected in OData service

Tags: 2013, odata

I am using the Tridion OData service to consume some data from a content-delivery database.

When I fetch a list of pages using `odata.svc/pages`, it is returning results in the browser. But when I publish any new page, it is not getting reflected in the results.

If I publish some new keywords, it's getting reflected.

I have checked cd_storage_conf and everything seems configured properly except that object cache is set to true (though I have got the server restarted). I have checked the content delivery database as well and the pages are getting reflected in the database.

Is it possible because of some deployer configuration setting?

Comment: Are HttpUpload and Odata Service referring same broker db & settings?

Comment: I didn't notice that odata service was set to return only 25 records. and hence it was returning only the top 25 records.

Comment: @rdhaundiyal, great find. You can answer your own question and maybe add a little detail like how you changes that limit of 25 items.

Comment: @Jan H, I didn't find this out as I was not having access to server but I will add the details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleague find out that maximum limit of records set to be retrieved was set to 25. In cd_webservice_conf of Odata deployment directory we increased the limit and it start displaying the results

```
<OData>
        <DefaultTop>25</DefaultTop>

 </OData>
```

PS. Filter parameter should be sent to odata service so that it will fetch only required records

Answer (score 5):

This suggests that your Cache is enabled in the OData Web Service, but you didn't configure the Cache Channel Service, which is required for notifications to flow from the deployer to the web application(s).

See this [section](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-67E7AAEA-8D59-419F-8289-5C1A57E19FD1) (login required) of the Documentation for details on how to configure cache synchronization. If this is just a dev machine, you could also consider disabling cache (in cd_storage_conf.xml).

Comment: But in that case it should not reflect keywords as well. I am able to retrieve newly published keywords

Comment: Maybe the cache implementation for Keywords is not working? If restarting your app shows the right results for pages, then it's clearly a cache issue. You could just turn cache off, and try it again?

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I have tried turning off the object cache but its still not working. Is there anything we are missing in odata configuration which is causing the problem.

Comment: That's weird, I certainly don't have that problem. Is it the same thing if you request /Pages in a browser? Maybe your client is caching the results?